# Finding the weighted mean of the frequency while also taking into account the amplitudes -using matlab / octave

Tags: matlab, math, octave

**I'm trying to use matlab / octave to find the weighted frequency (in hertz) of an array while also taking into account each frequencies amplitude.**

The array's 1st column are the frequencies (in hertz), the 2nd column is an amplitude and the 3rd column is another amplitude.  **Example code below just copy and paste into matlab or octave**

```
xfreq_orig=[0.00000;100;150;160;178;234;300;323;422;444];
yamp_orig=[7.5171e-20;1.1928e-05;5.4066e-06;4.1968e-05;3.0595e-05;3.6598e-05;2.8549e-05;4.3255e-05;2.2584e-05;2.7170e-05];
yamp_inv=[0.0090570;0.0090451;0.0090516;0.0090150;0.0090264;0.0090204;0.0090284;0.0090137;0.0090344;0.0090298];

a1=[xfreq_orig,yamp_orig,yamp_inv]
[row_orig_max,col_orig_max] = find(a1(:,2)==max(a1(:,2))) %max orig freq index
max_orig_freq=a1(row_orig_max,col_orig_max) %max orig freq

[row_inv_max,col_inv_max] = find(a1(:,3)==max(a1(:,3))) %max inv freq index
max_inv_freq=a1(row_inv_max,col_orig_max) %max inv freq

per_orig_amp=yamp_orig/sum(yamp_orig); %gets percentage of each amp
wgt_orig_tmp=xfreq_orig.*(yamp_orig.* per_orig_amp); %used to get orig weighted avg
wgtavg_orig=sum(wgt_orig_tmp)/sum(yamp_orig)  %to get orig weighted avg
sum(per_orig_amp) %check percentages equal 1

per_inv_amp=yamp_inv/sum(yamp_inv);%gets percentage of each amp
wgt_inv_tmp=xfreq_orig.*(yamp_inv.*per_inv_amp); %used to get inv weighted avg
wgtavg_inv=sum(wgt_inv_tmp)/sum(yamp_inv) %to get inv weighted avg
sum(per_inv_amp) %check percentages equal 1
```

The answers I get are:

```
    >>>a1 =

     0.00000     0.00000     0.00906
   100.00000     0.00001     0.00905
   150.00000     0.00001     0.00905
   160.00000     0.00004     0.00902
   178.00000     0.00003     0.00903
   234.00000     0.00004     0.00902
   300.00000     0.00003     0.00903
   323.00000     0.00004     0.00901
   422.00000     0.00002     0.00903
   444.00000     0.00003     0.00903

>>>row_orig_max =  8
>>>col_orig_max =  1
>>>max_orig_freq =  323
>>>row_inv_max =  1
>>>col_inv_max =  1
>>>max_inv_freq = 0
>>>wgtavg_orig =  35.305
>>>ans =  1
>>>wgtavg_inv =  23.089
>>>ans =  1
```

**I've checked that the sum of the percentages are equal to one** but instead of the weighted average being close to the **maximum frequency of 323** it's much less **wgtavg_orig =  35.305** and **wgtavg_inv =  23.089** any idea what's wrong with my formula/logic.

PS: I'm using octave 3.8.1 which should be compatible with matlab

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for the centre of mass? If so you could find by using

```
wgtavg_orig = xfreq_orig'*yamp_orig/sum(yamp_orig)
wgtavg_inv = xfreq_orig'*yamp_inv/sum(yamp_inv)
```

for which you would get

```
wgtavg_orig =

  269.5325


wgtavg_inv =

  230.9942
```

BTW, I am not familiar with Octave but in MATLAB you can use 
`[max_orig_freq, row_orig_max] = max(a(:,2))` instead of

```
[row_orig_max,col_orig_max] = find(a1(:,2)==max(a1(:,2)))
max_orig_freq=a1(row_orig_max,col_orig_max)
```